# Como definir uma subpasta como raiz de uma aplicação com HTACCESS?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewrite

Eu tenho uma determinada aplicação em PHP escrita com o framework Silex. Montei a estrutura de uma maneira onde apenas a pasta `public` seria a pasta onde eu apontaria o Apache pra lê-la.

Minha estrutura é mais ou menos essa:

```
projeto/
    app/
    resources/
    public/
        css/
        js/
        img/
        index.php
    vendor/
```

Assim, no meu Virtualhost do Apache, eu teria que apontar para `projeto/public`, pois esta seria a raiz do meu site.

Porém o bendito do meu servidor é shared host, então eu não posso fazer apontamento de forma nenhuma para pasta `public`.

Nesse servidor shared host, a leitura é feita a partir da pasta `public_html`, e não há nenhuma chance de eu colocar a pasta `public`.

Eu pretendo usar a pasta `public_html` para ser a raiz, adicionando os arquivos que estão dentro da minha pasta `projeto` (desenvolvimento local).

```
public_html/
    app/
    resources/
    public/
        css/
        js/
        img/
        index.php
    vendor/
```

Eu pretendo utilizar a estrutura. Eu sei que há uma maneira de direcionar tudo que é acessado na raiz para `public/index.php`

Estou fazendo assim:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

Eu não usei `!-d` propositalmente, pois não quero que ninguém acesse `app` e veja o diretório. E também tenho um sistema de rotas dentro de `index.php` que poderia ler `app/` como uma rota da aplicação (e não como pasta).

O problema é que se eu acessar `app/routes.php` por exemplo, vai aparecer uma página de erro, pois esse arquivo não deveria ser acessado, e sim somente a pasta `public`.

Eu quero saber se em `.htaccess` existe alguma maneira de redirecionar tudo absolutamente para uma pasta específica.

Quero que o meu `.htaccess` faça o apache reconhecer `public_html/public` como  raiz, ao invés de `public_html`.

Pois quero que o acesso a `public/css/default.css` seja reescrito para `css/default.css`. E não quero que outras pastas como `vendor`, `resources` e `app` esteja acessível.

Ou seja, quero que sempre `public_html/public` seja acessado como raiz.

Tem como fazer isso?

Eu tentei fazer `RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]` sem o `RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` e acabou dando um erro interno (devido a recursão gerada).

Comment: Eu acho que já fiz essa pergunta...

Answer (score -2):

Apesar de acreditar que seria mais facil realizar através do painel de controle do seu plano de hospedagem, você poderia tentar utilizar o seguinte htacess.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Isto irá fazer um redirecionamento de todas requisições para a pasta public, mas sinceramente não é a melhor alternativa.

Comment: Não funcionou. Ele redirecionou, ao invés de reescrever.

Comment: Vou ver se meu painel tem a opção que você citou